# Azure SQL DB - missing "Integration Services Catalogs" node

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have created a new Azure SQL DB in EastUS region & enabled SSIS Integration (in the same region) as per the article : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-deploy-ssis-packages-azure

Did not get any errors & powershell script got executed successfully (at least i was thinking so because i am able to see the SSISDB from SSMS 17.3
But I am not able to get the "Integration Services Catalogs" node as mentioned in the article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/lift-shift/ssis-azure-connect-to-catalog-database

Please let me know what else i need to do to get the "Integration Services Catalogs" node and SSISDB under it so that i will be able to deploy an SSIS package into "Integration Service Catalogs"-->SSISDB-->Projects.

Comment: Did you figure out the issue?

Comment: @asthasaraf please mark it as answer, if it solves ur challenge

Answer (score 2):

You need to connect the database **SSISDB** to see the "Integrations Services Catalogs" that is created by the SSIS Integration runtimes while you enabled SSIS integration.

As in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/lift-shift/ssis-azure-connect-to-catalog-database?view=sql-server-2017

1. SSIS Integration runtime creates a Database named as "**SSISDB**"
2. Navigate the database in the Azure environment and make sure it is created after the integration services is added in datafactory.
   [image]
3. Then open your Sql management studio and click on Connect and click on "Database Engine" enter your server credentials.

[image]

4. Click on option and then enter SSISDB in "Connect to database" textbox(initially you might have browse option, click on the browse to load the database).

[image]

5. Click connect then you should see the "Integration Services Catalogs" on the object explorer.

   [image]